# Delete redundant colname in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have data.table `x` that like

```
@ A B C D
1 2 3 4 n/a
5 6 7 8 n/a
.
.
.
```

I want to change it to

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
.
.
.
```

If there easy way to do? even in `data.table::fread` or `read.csv` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
headers <- names(x)[1:(length(x)-1)]
x <- x[, 1:(length(x)-1)]
names(x) <- headers
```

Comment: Your code would delete last col instead of first,
I change ```headers <- names(x)[1:(length(x)-1)]``` to ```headers <- names(x)[2:(length(x))]```
and it work, thanks!